# Tesseract OCR Visual Studio 2012 for Arabic Language

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract, arabic

Hi i have problem in  Tesseract OCR arbic in C#.
I am used Tessdata arabic.( 8 files) .
i have a good resultat for same words..but other words is not!
also The numbers are not displayed!

My code :

```
try
        {
            using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"C:\Users\C-bw\Documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\testOCR\testOCR\bin\Debug\tessdata", "ara", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                using (Pix img = Pix.LoadFromFile(@"D:\temp\nom.png"))
                {
                    using (Tesseract.Page page = engine.Process(img))
                    {
                        textnom = page.GetText();                    

                    }
                }
```

Any ideas how to debug this problem?

Thanks.